# get rid of tag "licence"

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-merge

Let's get rid of [licence](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licence) tag. Currently, there are 15 questions there.

Tag <s>name is misspelled, and the right tag for these questions is already there</s> means [the same](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/licence) as another tag - [license](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license), which in turn is already set as synonym of tag [licensing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licensing). Suggest to merge.

Comment: ChrisF is going to suspend you for this, licence is not a misspelling, it's the _proper_ spelling (and of course by proper I mean British) ;P

Comment: @YannisRizos "British"? what's this? I heard this is kind of ancient English? if seriously, then maybe it should be just synonimized instead of blacklisting. I'll leave it to Chris to decide, I am not that good in _lakhs_ of English dialects to judge :)

Comment: @YannisRizos. Surely *license* is a verb, and *licence* is a noun (similarly, *advise* and *advice*). I'd say the noun form makes more sense as a tag, but I suppose *licensing* also works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merged [licence](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licence) to [licensing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licensing), since it was the master tag.